# shared library - how to permanently set the path

Tags: export, shared-libraries, setenv

I am using a program that has some shared library that are usually installed to `/usr/lib`.

However for some reason i have to have these libs locally. So to make my program run (which depends on the former) I need to `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= ...` or add my local path permanently. This is ok for me but users of my software don't know this and for them this is too complicated. So my question: is there a way to automatically set the local path to my shared libs which are called by my program at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to automatically set the local path to my shared libs

Maybe.

If you are on Linux, and your application is installed *together* with shared library into say `/some/prefix/bin/app` and `/some/prefix/lib/libsharedlib.so`, then linking your application with:

```
gcc -o app -Wl,--rpath='$ORIGIN/../lib' main.o ... -lsharedlib
```

will achieve exactly the result you want (note: you can move *both* app and library into `/another/dir`, and it will still work so long as both the `lib` and `bin` directories are moved together).

Note: single quotes around `$ORIGIN` are required.

If you are on a platform that doesn't support `$ORIGIN`, the other common technique is to wrap the application in a shell script, which looks at `$0`, sets `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` appropriately, then execs the real application (which is often called `app.bin`, or `app.exe`).